# Stripe Subscription update the plan immediately with full amount

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I'm looking to update the customer's subscription, and the new plan price will be deducted immediately.

Consider the following scenario:

User is on Plan A($15 per month) and wants to update to Plan B($25 per month) in the middle of the month.

I want the user to charge $25 right away rather than prorate - I don't want the difference will be charged to the customer.

I also try with [proration_behavior='always_invoice'](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-proration_behavior) However, it is charge $10. I need $25 charged right away.

```
 subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve('sub_49ty4767H20z6a')
      Stripe::Subscription.update(
        subscription.id,
        {
          cancel_at_period_end: false,
          proration_behavior: 'none',
          items: [
            {
              id: subscription.items.data[0].id,
              price: 'price_1LcBtVHhBkzUOaGo0gvFmaMS'
            }
          ]
        }
      )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you’re looking to update a subscription without any prorations and to immediately charge for the upgraded price. The way to achieve this would be by specifically passing [proration_behavior:](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-proration_behavior) ‘none’ and [billing_cycle_anchor:](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-billing_cycle_anchor) ‘now’. Your code will look something like this:

```
Stripe::Subscription.update(
  subscription.id,
  {
    cancel_at_period_end: false,
    billing_cycle_anchor: ‘now’,
    proration_behavior: ‘none’,
    items: [
      {
        id: subscription.items.data[0].id,
        price: 'price_xxxxxxx'
      }
    ]
  }
)
```

Please note that this changes the billing cycle of the subscription and to learn more about billing_cycle_anchor please visit [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/billing-cycle#prorations).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with `proration_behavior` and `billing_cycle_anchor`.

You only need to pass these two properties while updating your subscription details using stripe API.

```
 subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve('sub_49ty4767H20z6a')
 Stripe::Subscription.update(
        subscription.id,
        {
          cancel_at_period_end: false,
          proration_behavior: 'none',
          billing_cycle_anchor: 'now',
          items: [
            {
              id: subscription.items.data[0].id,
              price: 'price_1LcBtVHhBkzUOaGo0gvFmaMS'
            }
          ]
        }
      )
```